# How to join 2 tables in access and display in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm having 2 tables

```
1.) invoice
 invoice_id
 invoice_date
 client_name
 client_address
 client_delivery_address
 total_basic_amount
 freight_rate
 delivery_rate
 advanced_amount
 pending_amount
2.)invoice_items
 ID
 invoice_id
 item_name
 qty
 rate
```

where invoice_items stores all the purchased items for that invoice. I want to display data in invoice / order report type datagrid view which will have fields like

```
invoice id | date | client name | delivery address | items | quantity | rate | total basic | freigh rate | delivery rate | advanced | pending amount
```

here is my query which I created

```
SELECT invoice.invoice_id, invoice.invoice_date, invoice.client_name, invoice_items.item_name, invoice_items.qty, invoice_items.rate, invoice.total_basic_amount, invoice.freight_rate, invoice.delivery_rate, invoice.advanced_amount, invoice.pending_amount
FROM invoice_items INNER JOIN invoice ON invoice_items.invoice_id = invoice.invoice_id;
```

But this returns something like this

[image: Output]

I want to display items under same invoice name in single row or somethig so later I can export them properly. Is there any way to do this in vb.net where I can display data in data gridvew ?? some other place to display data. like this I have to export that data in pdf and excel later.

I want to displya data something like this

```
Inv No | Date | client name | Items | qty | rate 
1 | 25-09-2022 | John | puri | 10 | 10
  | | | wada | 5 | 30 
  | | | pau | 20 | 3 
2 | 25-09-2022 | Mac | pepsi | 20 | 30 
3 | 25-09-2022 | Deo | puri | 20 | 60 
  | | | coke | 10 | 6
```

Comment: How are going to present `items` in a single DGV? What would `quantity` and `rate` be related to? You probably want a master / detail presentation with two DGVs, linked using a [DataSet with Relations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.relations) between Tables. Then, when you select an invoice in the first DGV, you see the details of that invoice in the other -- No code required, load the DataSet and set the Relation using the FK

Comment: What would be a "proper export"? What do you mean by "in a single row"? Exactly how do you want output to look? Create a sample table - as text, not an image.

Comment: I want to display data like we displays in invoice for ex;
Inv No | Date | client name | Items | qty | rate
1 | 25-09-2022 | John | puri | 10 | 10
   |                     |         | wada | 5 | 30
   |                     |         | pau | 20 | 3
2 | 25-09-2022 | Mac | pepsi | 20 | 30
3 | 25-09-2022 | Deo | puri | 20 | 60
  |                     |         | coke | 10 | 6

Comment: Question edited

Comment: Sample output does not reconcile with the image data. Build tables of representative data and output using that data. Use a table generator like https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables. Tables and queries are not meant to have blank cells like that, data loses associations. Would have to write records to a 'temp' table and generate a sequence ID that would be used to keep records in correct order. Otherwise, build a report and set textbox HideDuplicates property.